# Is it a good and secure idea to ensure external restrictive access with a JWT token as kind of API key?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization

Assume you are hosting an/or multiple API(s) in your company environment, which are consumed by internal clients. Now backend clients from your company's customer environments want to consume your API without user interaction. But you want to give them access in restricted scopes i.e. (partner:read, products:read etc.).

The idea is now giving each customer a JWT Token restricted to the specified scopes and valid until current business contract ends and signature it with your companies (high guarded) privateKey. Verification in the app will be done using public key, which is stored in each app. If the business contract will be extended, they will get a new token from your company side. In this approach the clients will provide the Authorization Header in each request. Is this a safe approach although the customer can decode the token and see it's content? Changes would make the signature invalid. So until this token is not stolen, it should be fine right?

Thanks a lot for help and best regards.

Comment: "customer can decode the token and see it's content". Yes, this is fine. The contents of JWTs are meant to be like this.

Comment: ok but is it a security concern, that a customer can see a decoded token, because it holds valid scopes with exact name? I mean the token is signed. So if the customer tries to modify it, it will directly be invalid signature. In my opinion no issues with that approach. But maybe i'am something missing?

Comment: It's not a security concern to see the scopes in the token because as you said, it can't be tampered with